# Reallocation sector count

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, speed, bad-sectors

my hard drive is working (copying files) very slow, However from this drive to external hdd copying speed is fine, but reverse is slow. after full format and repartitioning drive, result is same. i scanned that hdd test tool and report was such: - [hdd report result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qgLU.png). [hdd name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4N8p.png).

is my drive for garbage or could it be repaired? problem is software or hardware base?

Answer (score 0):

It says you had a 100 sector reallocation which is replacing 100 bad sectors with spare sectors.

This is a hardware problem, and can not be repaired.  The drive is getting old, and will die soon than later.  The slow down means your hard drive is probably doing at lot of error correcting, and is a bad sign.

You might be able to take some temporary measure, but that is it.  **chkdsk /r c:** will hide **bad** sectors, but **not** slow sectors.

In addition, you could buy spinrite, and do drive maintenance, but cost could be 50% to 100% of the software.  I seen 2tb for $60.

Comment: Ok, thank you cybernard. Indeed, as you said, every day it becomes more and more slow It seems I will have to buy new hard drive.